# CSS/HTML fade in/out on a image on hover not works - fade out not works

Tags: html, css

In my theme I have a portfolio item, an image. I want to ovveride the default slide in animation to fade in/out on hover animation.
When I hover on image, I have fade in animation with portfolio title text.
But when I move my cursor off the image, it immediately dissappears without fade out animation. How to correct that ?

My code for the animation is like below:

```
.image .image-extras {
  width: 101%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
 opacity: 0;
   text-align: center;
    transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
}
.image:hover .image-extras {
  opacity: 1;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #e10707 !important;
    transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
```

When I change word "opacity" in above code to 'all' I get the both in/out animations but the fade is reversed to default slide in from the top from my custom theme and I do not want that.

Comment: Please update the question with HTML and CSS both.

Comment: Ok, question title updated. Hope it is ok now.

Comment: can you post your code as a  demo?

Comment: You don't have to use `transition` on `:hover` selector

Comment: I think I do not know how to post it as demo, sorry

Is it possible that the animation comes from jquery and thats why I cant style it to my fade in/out effect ? jquery ovverides my css code ?

Comment: No idea. I made a demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/95gc66mb/) that just works: it fades out as well as in. So what's different between my demo and your website? You can change the source in the fiddle so that it demonstrates the problem.